# Why do I get this error installing virtualbox-4.1 on Arch?

Tags: kernel, arch-linux, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Virtualbox 4.1 from the [.run file](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) since Pacman had the 4.0 version only. But when I try installing the file using `sh filelocation/filename.run`, it gives me the following error-

> Please install the build and header files for your current Linux
>   kernel. The current kernel version is 2.6.38-ARCH

Is something broken in the kernel, or do I need to install something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the "kernel26-headers" package installed so VirtualBox can compile it's accompanying modules

Comment: I installed it using pacman, but it still shows the error. It's written "Please install the build..." so do I also need to build it, or do I just need to reboot?

Comment: Try running "/etc/rc.d/vboxdrv setup" to build the modules

Answer (score 1):

The current version in the repositories is [4.1.0-2.1](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/virtualbox/): your mirrors are not up-to-date.

Choose a properly synched mirror, and `pacman -Syy && pacman -Syu`